# Unable to parse xml without .xml extension

Tags: java, android

I cannot parse an xml from a [url](http://iwantallftp.cloudapp.net/iisCMS-staging/api/GetApps) that does not end with the .xml extension. However using the code below i can successfully parse the same xml when saved first to /res/raw.

Or when it is created with an .xml extension like [this](http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Firace.ph%2Ftools%2FAppAPI.xml&h=NAQHBi9vE) or 
"api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml" this for example.

Also adding `/?format=xml` to the end of the url does not solve the problem.

I thought that this has something to do with getting an HttpResponse but i cannot resolve the issue with my current code. I need to be able to retrieve the xml and parse it even without .xml extension.

```
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}
```

Here are the results of my logcat:

```
07-25 17:54:39.090: I/INFO(29276): Content:{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: entity","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentNullException","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.RuntimeFailureMethods.Requires(Boolean condition, String userMessage, String conditionText)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)\r\n   at iisCMS.Controllers.GetAppsController.PostApp(App app)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetExecutor>b__c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}
```

When i checked the response from the server, it was `application/xml` and i think i need `text/xml` any way to convert one to the other?

Comment: Post your logs from Logcat.

Comment: Are you sure that you have that xml to parse ?

Comment: What did you get back in `xml`? Evidently not XML, so check whether the response was not OK (200), but maybe required a redirect (302). Is POST of the URL correct? No GET? No parameters?

Comment: @JoopEggen, the info in the logcat was all i got back in xml.

Comment: Try http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientWithResponseHandler.java

Comment: @JoopEggen, using 'HttpGet' works, the responseBody shows the whole XML. But when i try to use that to in the DOM parser, the app just force closes.

Comment: The server should set the response type to XML. If you check your response header it might have set to text. If you can change the server end change it to work that way. Else pre process the text file and covert into XML

Comment: @dinesh707, the owner said that the response is in XML format not XML file, anyway to convert that to file after getting it so i can parse it?

Comment: You could try forgetting the String `xml` and immediately do `new InputSource(url);` - reason: the namespaces and other includes. Might take some time. Turn validating on.

Comment: @JoopEggen, i tried that, but still nothing. Is there any way to process the response so that i can read them as text/xml instead?

Answer (score 0):

As the comments show, now you have read a correct XML into the String variable `xml`.

Write the XML first to a file.

```
Path path = new Path("C:/Temp/test.xml");
Files.write(file, xml.getBytes("UTF-8"),
    StandardOpenOption.WRITE | StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

Then you can look into the file for irregularities, also with a browser. DTDs, schemas, namespaces, validation.